# CSS not applied to mapped font awesome icons

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm having a react/sass issue. When I use .map to create multiple font awesome icons for file formats, the styling is only being applied to the last element that is mapped. The mapping looks like this:

```
filelist.map((ext) => {
              return(
                (ext != 'docx')
                ? ext != 'txt' 
                  ? <span className='col col-xs-6'><i key={ext} className={'fa fa-file-'.concat(ext).concat('-o red')}></i></span>
                  : <span className='col col-xs-6'><i key={ext} className={'fa fa-file-text-o yellow'}></i></span>
                : <span className='col col-xs-6'><i key={ext} className={'fa fa-file-word-o blue'}></i></span>
              );
            })
```

So if the `filelist` was ['word', 'txt'] the styling would only work for the txt icon.

This is the SASS file that's being applied.

```
.fa-file-word-o:hover 
  font-size: 1.7em
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out

.fa-file-pdf-o:hover 
  font-size: 1.7em
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out

.fa-file-text-o:hover 
  font-size: 1.7em
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out
```

[so in this case: the single pdf works fine and the word doc enlarge. but the text and pdf on the multi file type line do not enlarge on hover.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAJml.png)

Comment: You went into the dev console and made sure that the `class` names are what you expect them to be, right?

Comment: @Andrew yes, here it is. from the dev console: ```<i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></I>``` and ```<i class="fa fa-file-word-o"></I>```

Comment: update: I've tested and the issue is only with hover. I was able to change the color of the mapped elements. So there is some strange behavior between css :hover and react .map

Answer (score 0):

[React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Make sure all your keys are unique

Comment: thanks, just checked by logging the ```ext``` and the keys are unique for each row.